# How to take apart parsed JSON results

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to take a JSON response from an external server but I cannot pull apart each field in the response.

```
<script>     
 function padronafip() {
    $.ajax({
        url:   'https://soa.afip.gob.ar/sr-padron/v2/persona/27293892046',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var JSONString = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(JSONString);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here follows the response:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"idPersona":27293892046,"tipoPersona":"FISICA","tipoClave":"CUIT","estadoClave":"ACTIVO","nombre":"SPITALE LAURA ANDREA","tipoDocumento":"DNI","numeroDocumento":"29389204","domicilioFiscal":{"direccion":"25 DE MAYO 198      - ESQUINA: RIVADAVIA","localidad":"PIGUE","codPostal":"8170","idProvincia":1},"idDependencia":111,"mesCierre":12,"fechaInscripcion":"1997-07-03","categoriasMonotributo":[{"idImpuesto":20,"idCategoria":44},{"idImpuesto":21,"idCategoria":11}],"impuestos":[20],"actividades":[474010,951100]}}
```

I want to fill differet text boxes with some of the data.

Thanks!

Comment: Dont stringify the javascript object that is returned in `data` then you can get at all the properties simply i.e. `data.success` and `data.data.idPersona` etc etc

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424518/accessing-json-data-from-jquery

Comment: Thanks!!! I was using data.idPersona instead data.data.idpersona...

Answer (score 1):

remove this:

```
var JSONString = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(JSONString);
```

you can then access your data in this manner:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://soa.afip.gob.ar/sr-padron/v2/persona/27293892046',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result.data.nombre);
    }
});
```